# Fabric.js text:changed event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I am working with `text:changed` event its working fine but I need to trigger a function when user stops typing not on every word change for example if user typing and stop typing for 2 seconds then trigger a function.

Below is my code to fire event on text change:

```
canvas.on('text:changed', function(e) {
    obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    newtext = obj.text;
    languageConverterEntoHn(newtext);

    $('#cteditinput').val(newtext);
    $('#cardalltexthex').empty();
    renderalltextfeomcanvas();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is generally called a `debounce` and you can find it in lodash library or you can write for yourself.

https://lodash.com/

```
// import lodash

var myFunction = function(e) {
   obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
   newtext = obj.text;
   languageConverterEntoHn(newtext);

   $('#cteditinput').val(newtext);
   $('#cardalltexthex').empty();
   renderalltextfeomcanvas();
}
var myFunctionDebounced = lodash.debounce(myFunction, 2000); // 2 seconds debounce
canvas.on('text:changed', myFunctionDebounced);
```

Comment: thanks  for reply i tried your solution. but its not working because of this error  "jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: lodash is not defined" i added  lodash.min.js ...but still  i am getting this error.

Comment: you have to import lodash in your project as you import fabric.